# Sitecore performance optimization - image storage

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Our website has about 200K images stored in sitecore database now. It runs more slowly than before. Does this large numbers of images stored in database will slow down the whole site?
If yes, how can I improve our image storage?

Thanks very much, our sitecore version is 6.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered setting up a CDN for your static assets? That would reduce load on your site and should speed it up.

Otherwise you might look at optimising the databases. Have a look at the Sitecore Optimisation Guide http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/cms_tuning_guide_sc60-64-a4.pdf

Comment: yes, we have a CDN for static resources, but our pictures will still grow up. Is storing images in database a good idea?

Comment: Sitecore recomends that you store them in the database as that gives you access to all the normal CMS features like versioning, security and workflow and it makes it easier to push items between CE and CD environments

Answer (score 0):

In general, it depends on whether front-end or back-end is slow.

If you experience issues even when the site is not loaded with huge number of requests - then you should probably upgrade hardware.

If it's caused by high website load - there are two rather simple options:

**1)** Use dedicated image server for Sitecore http://pentialized.dk/2011/01/02/dedicated-image-server-in-sitecore-part-2/

**2)** Integrate Media Library with CDN, CloudFront is really simple and powerfull, see the example here: http://herskind.co.uk/blog/2012/04/using-cloudfront-for-sitecore-media-content